# how to know when amazon machine instance start,stop and terminated? is there any way to send messege in sqs when instance start,stop and terminated?

Tags: amazon-sqs

who will notify when instance start or stop? i want to send message to sqs when instance start stop or terminated and sqs messeage will be read by DAS(Domain Administration server) asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You may write commissioning and decommissioning scripts for your EC2 instances, wherein you may also send some message to any SQS queue.